# Colour percentiles in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, graphing, percentile

```
plt.xticks(rotation=50)  #rotate x axis labels 50 degrees
plt.xlabel('Year')#label x axis Year
plt.ylabel('Index')#label y axis Index
plt.suptitle('Mahalanobis Distance Index Calculated from Yahoo Finance World Indices')#label title of graph Historical Turbulence Index Calculated from Daily Retuns of G20 Countries
plt.bar(systemicRiskMeasure[0][0].index,systemicRiskMeasure[0][0].values, width=20)#graph bar chart of Mahalanobis Distance
plt.show()
```

How can I colour the top 75% percentile in red and leave the rest blue?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Python. this is matlibplot